# How to make a loader for my PyQt5 Browser

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I am making a simple browser using PyQt5 and Python. I need to start a loading gif using

```
self.movie.start()
self.movie.stop()
```

but I need to call `self.movie.stop()` after the web page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the loadStarted and loadFinished signals to start and stop the animation:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie("loading.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.view, stretch=1)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, stretch=0)

        self.view.loadStarted.connect(self.movie.start)
        self.view.loadFinished.connect(self.movie.stop)

        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.qt.io"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```